# Backbone network in Object detection

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, object-detection

I am trying to understand the training process of a object deetaction deeplearng algorithm and I am having some problems understanding how the backbone network (the network that performs feature extraction) is trained.

I understand that it is common to use CNNs like AlexNet, VGGNet, and ResNet but I don't understand if these networks are pre-trained or not. If they are not trained what does the training consist of?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We directly use a pre-trained VGGNet or ResNet backbone. Although the backbone is pre-trained for classification task, the hidden layers learn features which can be used for object detection also. Initial layers will learn low level features such as lines, dots, curves etc. Next layer will learn learn high-level features that are built on top of low-level features to detect objects and larger shapes in the image.

[image]

Then the last layers are modified to output the object detection coordinates rather than class.

There are object detection specific backbones too. Check these papers:

- [DetNet: A Backbone network for Object Detection](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.06215)
- [CBNet: A Novel Composite Backbone Network Architecture for Object Detection](https://github.com/PKUbahuangliuhe/CBNet)
- [DetNAS: Backbone Search for Object Detection](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2019/file/228b25587479f2fc7570428e8bcbabdc-Paper.pdf)
- [High-Resolution Network: A universal neural architecture for visual recognition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/blog/high-resolution-network-a-universal-neural-architecture-for-visual-recognition/)

Lastly, the pretrained weights will be useful only if you are using them for similar images. E.g.: weights trained on Image-net will be useless on ultrasound medical image data. In this case we would rather train from scratch.

Comment: Hello, 
thank you for your reply! It is very clear! 
I am working on object detection using SAR images and now, I realized that I will have some problem using this pre-trained backbone network. 

Thank you again sir.